# Swift - Getting double ?? error when working with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am having trouble working with images from Parse. I have created a function to take all image files from a Parse class, and save them into a dictionary (with key value being the objectId). Any idea why and/or how to fix? Below are the codes:

```
  private func generateDictionaryOfImages(imageKeyToLookup: String, dictionaryKeyToReturn: String) {

    for object in objectList {
      var currentObjectId = object.objectId!
      var image = UIImage()

      let imageFile = object[imageKeyToLookup] as! PFFile

      imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if data != nil {
          if let imageData = data {
            image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
          }

        }
      })
// This imageDictionary is copied to the downloadedClientImages variable separately
      self.imageDictionary[currentObjectId] = image
    }
  }


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Profile") as! ProfileTableViewCell

    let title: String = grandCentral.returnValueForKeyAtIndexPath(indexPath.row, key: "forename") as! String
    let currentUserId: String = grandCentral.returnCurrentUserId()

// Error is generated here. '@lvalue UIImage??' is not convertible to 'UIImage'
    let image: UIImage = downloadedClientImages[currentUserId]
    cell.setCell(title, image: image)

    return cell
  }
```

Comment: No surprise here.  What's the question?

Comment: How are `self.imageDictionary` and `downloadedClientImages` declared?

Comment: @ndmeiri    self.imageDictionary = [String: UIImage]()
and   var downloadedClientImages:   [String: UIImage?]   = [String: UIImage]()
then     downloadedClientImages = grandCentral.returnDictionaryOfImages()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unwrap optional after you access it from a dictionary.

```
if let image = downloadedClientImages[currentUserId] {
    cell.setCell(title, image: image)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the image coming back as optional? I didn't specific the UIImage as being optional at any point? Slightly confused why this issue has occurred...?

Comment: Dictionary wouldn't know what to return if a key is not found so it returns optional and forces you to check it.